# how to adjust the webview width relating to screen size in android? need a hack

Tags: android, webview

Im using a customized webview as follows

```
<merge
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:MyWebView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mds.android.mireader.webview"   android:background="#FFFFFF"  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">


 <com.mds.android.mireader.webview.MyWebView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:id="@+id/myweb"     **android:layout_width="318px"**  android:layout_height="fill_parent" > </com.mds.android.mireader.webview.MyWebView>
```

im doing some  thing strange, for that i need to satisfy following condition

condition: **webview width should always divisible by 3**

So i can't give fixed value or fill_parent in above xml file.For example  if i give fill_parent it works fine for portrait(assume HVGA emulator with portrait width=480 which is divisible by 3)but no success for landscape(bcz landscape width 800 which is not divisible by 3).

Solution  should work for both orientation change and device change"

Im struggling with 1 or 2 pixel values difference and it will be solved if i satisfy that **condition**. TIA ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HI,

You can get the height and width of the screen using following piece of code:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Now you have the width you can check whether it is divisible by 3 or not. If yes then well and good, otherwise you can subtract the modulus(width%3) from the original width and set it as the width of your webview.

**Add A View Programmatically:**

Sample XML:

```
<LinearLayout (define id:testLayout, width, height here> </LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.testlayout);
// create an object of your webview and set all the properties you want like background color etc.
MyWebView myWebView = new MyWebView(); 

linLayout.addView(myWebView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(<my calculated width>, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

PS: you dont have to add the webview object in your XML file. "addView" function will add your webview inside your linear layout object.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @mudit "set it as the width of your webview." how can i do that? that is the main  problem...

Comment: @mudit see edited question. i want to set the layout width at run time before loading a page in to webview... and thinking of layoutparams but i dnt knw how to use them...

Comment: I guess than, you can create a simple Linear layout in your XML file and then you can add your Custom WebView progreamatically. Check the updated answer on how to add it.

Comment: @mudit  your code looking good but im new to android... do you have any complete example like this? my doubt is do i need to place webview layout inside testlayout? how to identify web view with id?