# webview is not displaying website properly android

Tags: java, android

Hi i have used webview and below is my code

```
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;


    RelativeLayout linLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    myWebView = new WebView(this); 

    linLayout.addView(myWebView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
```

i want to adjust webview width and heigh with screen size but this code is not working properly and webview is not displaying properly

**UN-USED SPACE is i have written manually it is blank space which should not display**

[image]

can any body solve? how to fix webview size according to screen size

for setting webview according to screen size i got answer from [how to adjust the webview width relating to screen size in android? need a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040886/how-to-adjust-the-webview-width-relating-to-screen-size-in-android-need-a-hack) but it is not working

Comment: is you want to set web view to get all screen..

Comment: Hello Sumedh Tambat ya i want full screen but look here it is displaying with scroll view

Comment: your problem is your RelaytiveLayout. please post your xml code here.

Comment: @SuryanarayanaReddy it was 5 years old question, it was already resolved...

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit super,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this i think this i what you want

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        this.setContentView(mWebView);
    }
```

For Scaling i think you can try this piece of code its worked for me

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width=display.getWidth();

String data="<html><head><title>Example</title><meta name=\"viewport\"\"content=\"width="+width+", initial-scale=0.65 \" /></head>";
data=data+"<body><center><img width=\""+width+"\" src=\""+url+"\" /></center></body></html>";
webView.loadData(data, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: what is not working what exactly you want not clear from your images

Comment: but djhacktorregorn html page is displaying from server side i am loading one url http://in-touchm.com/social/petvet/ check it

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit there is url in string data where you can paste your own url that will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

use following code in java

```
setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

and code in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Comment: I have used also this myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);  <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar" />

Comment: still same problem is occuring

Comment: i think you use some base layout and in that you use web view...and on button click you called different url..m i right..if yes then use fill parent of fixed parameter to height and width...it may work

Comment: no no i have used your code at the first time then i got another answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040886/how-to-adjust-the-webview-width-relating-to-screen-size-in-android-need-a-hack this. so i have changed my code with above code but could not find solution

Comment: humm..now i can only say by looking at d code on your provided link that you have to fix linear layout width and height...

Comment: yup now u got ... but not linearlayout it's relative layout

Comment: but how!! i have used the code who has accepted answer in that he tolding that it's working fine

Comment: can you try using linear layout using xml nt pragmatically if not necessary...beause sometimes relative layout may not work properly..